# How to stop touch events in android WebView when its content is scrolling?

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to disable touch event in android WebView when its content is scrolling. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a scroll event listener to the WebView like so:

```
 webView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                
            }
        });
```

(requires API 23)

Then inside it add a touch even listener that returns true like so:

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

It disables all touch events on a WebView because the touch listener is executed before the default touch behavior of the WebView.

So the final result will be:

```
 webView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
                  
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It will also prevent you from clicking on the link, won't go to next page

```
webview.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
webView.setLongClickable(false);
webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            event.setLocation(webview.getWidth() + 1, webview.getHeight() + 1);
        }
        return event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to Disable / Enable the touch event..

```
 private fun DisableScreen(status: Boolean) {
    if (status) {
        window?.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
        );
    } else {
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
    }
}
```

This will disable touch on Screen and you can enable touch again by clearing the Flag.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `WebView` is incapable of handling CANCEL event and treats it as UP.
My workaround is to use a GestureDetector to figure out clicks and dispatch them, and drop anything else:

```
val gd = GestureDetector(context, object : SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return onTouchEvent(e.also { it.action = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN }) &&
            onTouchEvent(e.also { it.action = MotionEvent.ACTION_UP })
    }
})
setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
    gd.onTouchEvent(event)
    true
}
```